# changes on browser moved locally but no changes

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a website built in `Reactjs` and `SCSS`.
I'm doing some `SCSS changes on the browser, however when I move those changes to Visual Studio,
what is supposed to be is when I refresh the browser the changes should appear. however, the changes lost to note that some changes were done successfully to other parts.

I have done search since a couple of days ago and this is what I found
that I should disable caches also delete them plus cookies. I did that.  I have also tried to open it in incognito mode
but the problem still appears

link for the sample of the website
[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-worker-ijleu)

so i got this error in console log

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `gray3` supplied to `ForwardRef(Typography)`, expected one of ["initial","inherit","primary","secondary","textPrimary","textSecondary","error"]
```

what I am missing?

Comment: first check if its really cache , try using incognito mode.

Comment: i have tried using incognito mode too. but the problem still appears

Comment: It's nice that you provided a code sample. However, we cannot see the error you are talking about, because the example is not working. Moreover, the error you are showing is about a `gray3` property, which is not in the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the browser by hitting `CTRL` + `F5`. This way, the cache will be cleaned, and the CSS changes will be applied

Comment: i refreshed the page, didnt work

Comment: So when you refresh, the changes are not applied ? The server is on, and you are watching at the right page ? Maybe providing a reproducible example would help

Comment: i have just notice that there is an error in console log

Comment: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at TopPromotion

Comment: This is an other issue. Please post a new question about it, and please provide a minimal reproducible example, so we can help you to understand what you are doing wrong

Comment: Well, it could be, but I have no clue, since I don't know the context ^^ In order for us to help you, it is strongly advisable to provide some example as I said :)

Comment: the problem the website is a huge one
i cant share it all here
what is your suggestion?

Comment: Yes I totally understand! That's why you could provide us a minimal reproducible example, on this website for instance: https://codesandbox.io/
You can install the required dependencies (react, and so one), and provide just a simple page where we can reproduce your issue. This way, we can be sure that if we can reproduce the issue on this live example, it is not linked to your local setup/configuration

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-worker-ijleu

Comment: There are some errors with the source code

Comment: please tell me is this snippet is enough?

Comment: No, since it is not showing anything because of the errors in the code. It should be a working example. But you can provide a very simple snippet, that just print a Hello World which is styled with scss for instance, so it is similar to your issue

Comment: No, just remove the part that doesn't work, and leave a small but working example. The goal here is just to have a page that is styled with scss, right ?

Comment: Here, you can find some useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should also pay attention to the version of the dependencies, so they match what you have for your project

Comment: I got what you meant, but isnt here anyway of chatting privately?
so i can send you my email

Comment: or if you can type your email so i can send you the project
it would be easier for both us

Comment: Technically I could, but the goal is that you make the effort to locate the bug by yourself, so maybe you are able to fix it by yourself, otherwise we can help you on this. And you should show what you tried. But it's better to stay here, so everyone will be able to see your problem, and the solution. I hope you understand!
So please update your post, with the link to your minimal reproducible example (that should work). Read the article I sent you, it is very useful, you may even fix the issue by yourself!

Comment: thank you for your ultimate help.
i tried to remove some unnecessary parts but this is what i got in the end

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-lake-3563f?file=/src/App.js:270-273

Comment: would you please take a look at the question again?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible and working example. You should consider writing it from scratch, and include only necessarily part that would help to show where is your problem

Answer (score -1):

I found out that i was editing the wrong file
since the project is not built by me

thank you everyone who tried to help me